# Linq Query Slowing Down Global Asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq

One of our devs put this in the Global.asax code, `Application_Start` method:

```
IEnumerable<object> result = from t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IClassId)) &&
    t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
    select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IClassId;

List<IGrouping<Guid, object>> lst = result.GroupBy(x => ((IClassId)x).ClassId)
    .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
    .ToList();
```

When I ran the Performance Profiler in Visual Studio, it was identified as a "Hot Path".

I'm fairly new to this and was wondering why this would cause a slowdown.

Comment: You're not giving nearly enough info to effectively answer this question, however, just because something is identified as a "hot path" doesn't mean it is. That is usually relative to the other methods or extensions. Increasing your test case coverage and evaluating the results. That said, LINQ is generally not the fastest as it works in methods that work with a wide range of results. What are you trying to find? You might code specifically to that and avoid LINQ all together.

Comment: This code will go through whole assemblies which are used by application and search there for IClassId Interface containing object and look if that has default constructor and create it's instance. If you have many assemblies this will take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like some auto-creation code for classes with a default constructor that implement IClassId interface in the web app domain.

This is using reflection to get an instance of all of these classes and store them on an array. So, yes, this could be slow or super slow depending on how many classes fulfill these conditions.

This is not heavy testing but I think it'll illustrate the issue. I've created a new empty project, created `IClassId` interface and measure the average time to run. I don't even have any class implementing the interface so the result set will be empty:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //measure the running time
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    IEnumerable<object> result = from t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IClassId)) &&
                t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
        select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IClassId;

    List<IGrouping<Guid, object>> lst = result.GroupBy(x => ((IClassId)x).ClassId)
        .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
        .ToList();
    stopWatch.Stop();

    var elapsed = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

}
```

On average it took 500 ms to run this piece of code with no implementations and also no other assemblies loaded into my app domain than default VS project template assemblies. There are no just a few of them however. About 28000 in my case. You could do the same and see how many you have:

```
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Count();
```

> Conclusions:

I'd recommend not to use this code but setup a proper IoC container instead, so instances can be created on demand and injected into constructors when needed instead of create them all during application startup.